# Could not find rake-13.0.6 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I've done a bit of gem updating on a project I'm working on due to git security complaints, and now I'm running into an issue: the web project page doesn't work with an error `"Web application could not be started"` and complaining that `"Could not find rake-13.0.6 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)"` (despite it being there), and attempting to run rake (namely I need rake ts:restart) results in the title error: *removed due to obsolescence, see the edit*.

EDIT:

I've ended up rolling back my project to pre-update gemfile and older versions of ruby and rails, but now I'm having this issue again (at least not the one with rake anymore). The page keeps giving me the `Could not find rake-13.0.6 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)` error.

When I try to run `rake ts:start` it fails with the errors:

```
...
bind() failed on 127.0.0.1, retrying...
FATAL: bind() failed on 127.0.0.1: Address already in use
```

I've tried a whole bunch of stuff and now looking for suggestions on how to troubleshoot this.

Comment: The error you're getting from `rake ts:start` suggests that Sphinx is already running - you should be able to find the process via `ps aux | grep searchd`.

Comment: yeah, there was that too. For whatever reason ts:stop and ts:restart didn't properly shut down the existing searchd process, which I had to pkill myself and after that it started working properly again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turned out that my nginx was not configured correctly and it was pointing to now missing rvm version of ruby, which I have replaced with an rbenv version.